# pip in docker getting can't open file '/usr/local/bin/pip': [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running my python (django) app inside a container (using django cookiecutter project template). Everything was working well, but suddenly it failed to build with the following error:

```
Step 5/13 : RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt ---> Running in 4118795a1036 /usr/local/bin/python: can't open file /usr/local/bin/pip': [Errno 13] Permission denied ERROR: Service 'django' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /requirements/local.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I followed the official docker documentation about permissions when I first installed docker (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/)

Image used: python:3.6-alpine

Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I have already tried to prune the docker system (`docker system prune`) and tried to build the project with `sudo` (`sudo docker-compose build`) with no success.

Here is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add mariadb-dev \
  && apk add mysql-client \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt 
(...)
```

Has anyone ever faced this problem or knows any way to fix it? I've been struggling with it for hours and I've (literally) run out the ideas. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: can you add your docker-compose file?

Comment: Hi Miki, sometimes python:3.6-alpine, or any alpine singled container have problems related to dependencies on a pip installation, can you try changing it to a ubuntu distro and then installing python and post here the results?

Answer (score 0):

1. Trying removing python3-dev from the packages you install, as well as py-cffi. The Python in the alpine packages is different than the Python in the Docker image, you don't want to install Alpine Python stuff if you can help it.
2. I would suggest avoiding Alpine. The motivation for Alpine is smaller images, but because binary wheels don't work with Alpine you need to compile packages... which means you need to install a compiler, which makes your images bigger. If you switch to Debian base image `python:3.6-slim-buster` (and I would argue you should for other reasons too: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/) you will simplify your life.